# Given an $n\times n$ sized grid of dots $\forall n>2$, find the minimal value of segments needed to draw through all points, not holding off the hand.

Tags: graph-theory, induction

Given is an $n\times n$ square of dots (so $3\times3$ is a $2 \times 2$ square, which means $9$ dots: corners of the squares).

**What have I already achieved and proven?**

Obviously for $n=1$: The answer is one: Through one point one line is enough and need to touch all points.

For $n=2$, the answer is three.

For $n=3$, it's not five, it's four as known in the popular problem:

[image: Setup][image: Solution]

Then I decided to check how we got here. I drew the setups for $n=4, 5, 6, 7, 8$ where the value of segments was equivalently $6, 8, 10, 12, 14$ using different strategies to connect the dots. I was stuck there for some hours, but in the end I proved with induction that for $n > 2$ the amount of segments *possible* is $2(n-1)$

You took the picture above ($^2$) and just continued the diagonal one more, and always added two more lines for one higher n:

[image: Proof]

Since we arrive in the relative the same position, any $n\times n$ dots grid can be filled with $2n - 2 = 2 (n-1)$ segments, without holding off the pencil. (We originally just draw spirals, which was $2n$, the we started to draw a kind of Z/snake figure which was $2n-1$ for all $n$)

**What do I still have to do?**

I proved that it's possible, but not that it's the minimum. If it's the minimum, **how to prove that the amount of segments needed is actually minimal**, and you can't go further? Is the formula below correct (which is simply my hypothesis)? **Is the current formula showing the absolute minimum at all right now?**

$$
\left\{\begin{array} \\
t_1 = 1 \\
t_2 = 3 \\
\forall n > 2, n \in \mathbb{N}: t_n = 2(n-1)
\end{array}\right.
$$

Because I have the feeling, that for, e.g. hundred times hundred square, the square will not consist of $2(100-1) = 198$ segments, but perhaps even 195?